AWS CDK does not deploy updated Lambda Layers
The project is being developed along with "aws-cdk": "2.79.1" and typescript. The root directory is connect-backend.  There is a directory connect-backend/assets/lambda-layers/nodejs. Currently I am installing npm packages inside this directory for the purpose of using them as lambda-layers. But deploy them to pipeline using Docker.
//package.json

{
    "name": "lamda-layer",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "@sparticuz/chromium": "^119.0.2",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.11",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
        "html-docx-js": "^0.3.1",
        "node-html-parser": "^6.1.13",
        "puppeteer-core": "^21.6.1",
        "quoted-printable": "^1.0.1"
    }
}

Inside the connect-backend-stack.ts file, defined the layer path and name as below;
const lambdaLayer = new LambdaLayers(this, buildConfig, {
  layerName:  "AllInOneV2",
  layerPath: "./assets/lambda-layers",
  layerDescription : "Layer containing nodejs modules"
});

The construct-lambda-layers.ts file;
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { BuildConfig } from './build-config';
  
export interface LambdaLayerProps {
  readonly layerName: string;
  readonly layerPath: string;
  readonly layerDescription: string;
}

export class LambdaLayers extends Construct {

    public readonly lambdaLayer: lambda.LayerVersion;

    constructor(scope: Construct, buildConfig: BuildConfig, props: LambdaLayerProps) {
        super(scope, `${buildConfig.envPrefix}LambdaLayer-${props.layerName}`);

        this.lambdaLayer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, props.layerName, {
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(props.layerPath, {
                exclude: ['*', '!package.json', '!package-lock.json'],
                bundling: {
                  image: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X.bundlingImage,
                  command: ['bash', '-c', 'mkdir /asset-output/nodejs && cd $_ &&'
                    + 'cp -v /asset-input/nodejs/{package.json,package-lock.json} . &&'
                    + 'npm ci'],
                  environment: { HOME: '/tmp/home' },
                },
              }),
            compatibleArchitectures: [lambda.Architecture.X86_64, lambda.Architecture.ARM_64],
            compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_18_X],
            description: props.layerDescription,
        });
    }
}

My problem is when some new npm packages are installed and tried to deploy, but I see only the previous npm packages in AWS lambda layers.
Here what I already tried to solve this issue, but could not solve the issue;

changed layerName in layerName:  "AllInOneV2",

deleted the already existing lambda layer file in aws and redeployed.

Changed local directory name nodejs to nodejs2 and redeployed

Tried to change the bundling command to remove node modules first:
command: ['bash', '-c', 'mkdir /asset-output/nodejs && cd $_ &&' + 'rm -rf node_modules && '+ 'cp -v /asset-input/nodejs/{package.json,package-lock.json} . &&'+ 'npm ci'],


In the above last two cases (3 and 4), I got below error

Need help to solve this issue.

FYI - exclude has no effect when bundling is specified.
